# Should we answer ambiguous questions with no code?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Here is an example. [How do I get an element from the source of a page in selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398221/how-do-i-get-an-element-from-the-source-of-a-page-in-selenium-python)

Should this be done? or not?

Comment: There is a close reason for this - two in fact. Either "unclear" or "needs debugging details". Note that lacking code isn't *necessarily* ambiguous or close-worthy, however, if a question says something like "I'm trying to get all odd numbers from an array and it doesn't work" then shows now code, ithat's not really answerable as we cannot guess what the exact error is and suggest a fix.

Comment: As I said, no code *doesn't necessarily* mean it's unclear. There are questions one can ask that don't involve code and are on topic. E.g., questions about IDEs.

Comment: Of course I know that. My question is regarding the questions that themselves are not clear and also don't have any code whatsoever. I hope you understand with the example. I see many such everyday.

Comment: The question was somewhat unclear before, but now that it's been edited, I think it's pretty reasonable. Probably a duplicate, but I wouldn't call it too broad.

Comment: ambiguous, and no code, are different problems. Both are also subjective, in that someone with a lot of experience in a given language and in answering questions for said language can often recognize the problem with less information. No general rule is needed, use your judgement based on your experience.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Since you preferred to delete your most recent question, here's a pro tip for searching stack overflow with your concern of interest: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22python%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22python%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.15425j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Your question's fine, but I think people think the premise is a bit silly.  You wouldn't entertain ambiguous questions from random strangers anywhere else on Earth; why would Stack Overflow entertain them?

Answer (score 15):

If the question is ambiguous, then the answers can only be ambiguous.  Ambiguity is not what we want to have for our answers, so I would argue that it should be closed instead.

Comment: I thought so. Hence the question. Let me just wait and see if there is an opposing view of some sort on this.

Comment: I would rather that people suggest the OP to improve their question. However, I see it multiple times that people answer vague questions with general answers, which I think is bad and should not be done.

Comment: @AbhishekRai correct, it shouldn't be done. Although, consider that it's *possible* that it might be clear to the answerers. Although, sometimes people do answer with guesses.

Comment: @AbhishekRai "I would rather that people suggest the OP to improve their question" - you mean like Aaj Kaal did [five minutes after the question was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398221/how-do-i-get-an-element-from-the-source-of-a-page-in-selenium-python#comment115620818_65398221)?

Comment: @F1Krazy Lol. That guy wrote like a lawyer. I said "suggest" ..It means to implore the user to kindly add some code. Not say "Cease you ..codeless entity, lest you be thrown in the dungeon of closed questions" :))